# bot spam in discor creating

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, spam

```
import discord
import time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected to Discord! {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == '"spam':
        while True:
            await message.channel.send('SPAM')
            time.sleep(2)
            if message.content.lower() == '"stop':
                break


client.run('token')
```

Need to make a bot in discord
when the user enters (*"spam*), the bot starts spamming messages until someone enters the (*"stop*) command.

I tried to make a discord bot(program code at the top) that, when users entering a command (*"spam*), starts spamming one message (*SPAM*) until some user enters a command (*"stop*) **Well, my bot does not stop when entering the command (*"stop*), it continues to spam further**
**How to stop a bot using a command (that is, by entering the command (*"stop*) into the chat discord server bot stopped)**

thanks

Comment: You need to separate the while loop into an extra function and then maybe use bool flags to communicate between on_message and the loop

Answer (score 0):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()
d = False # if spam
mc = 0 # channel of message


async def mtask():
    await client.wait_until_ready() # if client is ready
    global mc
    while not client.is_closed():
        if d: # if spam
            await mc.send("SPAM") # spam message
        await asyncio.sleep(2) # sleep time


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global d, mc
    if message.content.lower() == '"spam':
        d = True

    if message.content.lower() == '"stop':
        d = False
    mc = message.channel


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected to Discord! {0.user}'.format(client))


client.loop.create_task(mtask()) #create task
client.run('asdadaw')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == '"spam': 
        while True:
            await message.channel.send('SPAM')
            time.sleep(2)
            # here you should compare the new message with "stop not the old
            if message.content.lower() == '"stop':
                 break
```

it won't stop because you didn't take new input from the user the second if condition is useless cuz the message will always be "spam here is what you should do after the bot sends SPAM to take input from the user then check if the input =="stop. sorry, I can't help with code I didn't use dicord.py before but I think you should be able to create a command to take user input and save it to variable the do the if check or something like that